# Организация счётчика вызова функции

Tags: c++, функции, переменные, счетчики

Получила задание (С++): "Продемонстрируйте работу со статическими переменными. Один из возможных вариантов - организация счетчика вызовов функции". Это одно из заданий по теме указатели, я не понимаю как связать это задание с темой, учитывая то, что передачу параметров по ссылке мы ещё не учили. Возможно ли как-то связать тему с кодом? Правильно ли я поняла задание?
В задании сказано, что это "один из вариантов". Как ещё можно выполнить задачу?

```
void initialStaticVar()
{
    static int s_var = 0;
    s_var++;
    cout << "Static Var = " << s_var << endl;
}

int main()
{
    initialStaticVar();
    initialStaticVar();
    initialStaticVar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вытащите счетчик из функции (в тот же файл) и добавьте функцию, возвращающую его значение. `static int foo_cnt = 0; int get_foo_cnt() {return foo_cnt;} void foo () { foo_cnt++; ... остальной код функции ...}`

Comment: Связать тему с указателями можно. Переменные храняться в трёх областях памяти. Статической, динамической и в стеке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статические переменные создаются при старте программы и оканчивает свою жизнь при завершении.

Есть много понятий переменных с обозначением статические.

1. Глобальная переменная без обозначения **static**.
2. Глобальная переменная с обозначением **static**.
3. Локальная переменная внутри функции.
4. Глобальная переменная внутри пространства имён.
5. Статическая переменная внутри объявления класса.

### Глобальная переменная без обозначения **static**

header.h :

```
extern int i ;
```

main.cpp :

```
int i = 0 ;
```

function.cpp :

```
# include <header.h>
..
i = i + 1 ;
```

к переменной `i` можно будет обратиться если в её предварительно объявить как `extern` (*может находиться в другом файле*).

### Глобальная переменная с обозначением **static**

function.cpp :

```
static int i = 1 ;
```

main.cpp :

```
static double i = 2.0 ;
```

Здесь обозначение `static` обязывает уменьшать область видимости переменной `i` только внутри `.cpp` файла. И в разных файлах эта переменная будет иметь **разные** значения или даже разные типы.

### Локальная переменная внутри функции

```
int function1(int i){
  static int sum = 0 ;
  sum += i ;
  return sum ;
}

double function2(double i){
  static double sum = 0 ;
  sum += i ;
  return sum ;
}
```

Здесь переменных `sum` в программе две штуки. Но область видимости только в своей функции. Присваивание нулю этим переменным будет происходить только один раз при первом вызове функции. А если эти функции не будут бызваны вообще, то и эти переменные не будут инициилизированы никогда.

*Эта переменная храниться не в стеке, а в глобальном пространстве и не теряет своё значение при выходе из функции.*

### Глобальная переменная внутри пространства имён

```
namespace NS {
  int stat = 1 ;
}
namespace NS2 {
  double stat = 2.0 ;
}
```

Здесь статические переменные имеют одинаковые имена, но имеют разные значения. К ним можно обращаться так : `NS::stat` , `NS2::stat`.

### Статическая переменная внутри объявления класса

```
class C{
public :
  static int sum ;
} ;

int C :: sum = 0 ;
```

Здесь переменная `sum` будет храниться в единственном экземпляре для всех членов класса `C`. И обращаться можно так-же, как если бы были объявлены  в пространстве имён. *Если политика разрешений класса позволяет.*

Answer (score 3):

Живут достаточное :) время глобальные переменные и статические переменные функции.

Отсюда и варианты.

Ваш:

```
int testFunc(...)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    ...
    return counter;
}
```

С глобальной переменной:

```
[static] int counter = 0;   // static - в зависимости от конкретного проекта

void testFunc(...)
{
    counter++;
    ...
}
```

Или со статической переменной в другой функции:

```
int countFunc(bool check = false)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    if (!check) counter++;
    return counter;
}

void testFunc(...)
{
    countFunc();
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
    cout << "testFunc was callsed " << countFunc(true) << " times\n";
    ...
}
```

Понятно, что конкретные функции могут изменяться в зависимости от ваших потребностей.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно просто добавить указатели к статическим переменным, можно сделать сделать так (предполагаю, что не учили передачу по ссылке,  но учили передачу по указателю):

```
int* getCounter(){
    static int c = 0;
    return &c;
}

void incrementCounter(){
    ++(*getCounter());
}
void printCounter(){
    std::cout << *getCounter();
}
void testFn(){
    incrementCounter();
    std::cout << "testFn\n";
}
```

UPD:
Еще вариант (обычно плохой на практике, но в целом корректный):

```
static int* counterPtr;
void incrementCounter(){
    ++(*counterPtr);
}
int main(){
    counterPtr = new int(0);
    incrementCounter()
    incrementCounter()
    std::cout << *counterPtr;
    delete counterPtr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж (при таком развитом API) имеет смысл сделать соответствующий класс-счетчик...

Comment: @Harry , по моему опыту, в случае подобных университетских задач это плохая идея. А так, конечно,  getCounter может возвращать ссылку/указатель на статический объект класса с методами increment и print